# JFrame turns small after calling Canvas.setSize() and JFrame.pack() after the program is started

Tags: java, swing, canvas, resize, jframe

I'm creating a program and I want to be able to set the size of it "on the fly" (when the program is running). I try to do this by calling `Canvas.setSize(width, height)` and then `JFrame.pack()` on the `JFrame` which contains the `Canvas`. The problem is that after calling those methods, the JFrame resizes so that only the icon and the close and minimize buttons are visible. How can I change the size while the program is running? Do I have to call something else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use the `setSize()` method on any component you add to a `JFrame`.

Swing uses layout managers. The `pack()` method will invoke the layout manager and the layout manager will generally use the preferred size of the component to determine the size/location of the components.

I guess your `Canvas` class is doing custom painting, and therefore has a preferred size of zero by default, so there is nothing to display.

The solution is to override the `getPreferredSize()` method in your `Canvas` class to return an appropriate size.

Also, don't call you class `Canvas`, because there is an AWT class by that name, so it gets confusing. If you are using the AWT Canvas class, you should be using the `JPanel` class instead, for custom painting.

Comment: I use a custom class, `Display`, which extends `Canvas`, and I use `Canvas` because I'm making a game, so I need the `BufferStrategy` etc. Also, when I create the `Display` (or `Canvas`), I set its size with `display.setPreferredSize(width, height)`, and I've tried doing this during runtime when changing the size too, but it doesn't work. So I should override `Canvas.getPreferredSize()` so that it returns the size I want for the `Display` (`Canvas`)?

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12, you would override the Display class, since this is the class that contains the custom code and therefore knows what the proper size of the component should be.

Comment: It doesn't work anyway... The method looks like this:  
    `@Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }`

Sorry for the bad formatting... Comments...

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12, sure it works assuming the rest of your code is correct because this is the way layout managers work. Create a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to learn the basics of how this should be done. That is create a custom JPanel and override the `getPreferredSize()` method and add the panel to the frame and then pack() the frame. Prove that the simple concept works. Then debug your code to see what the different is. If the SSCCE doesn't work, then you have simple code to post. We can't guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I use a `Thread`, which runns the `Game`, which implements `Runnable`. In the beginning of the `run` method, I set a size for the `Display`, and calls `JFrame.pack()`, and also some other properties. Then, I try to change the size of the `Display`. This is because I try to make the resolution selectable by the user, as in most games, and I'm implementing and testing this system now, when I don't have extremely much code. I have tried without changing the resolution after the frame is created, so the code works, except for the part which is supposed to change te resolution during runtime.

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12, why did you reply with a comment? We can't help without a SSCCE. There is no trick. You change the property of the panel to a size you want. The method then invokes revalidate() on the panel. Finally you will want to invoke pack() again on the frame. If you don't post the code we can't guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Okay, thanks! My SSCCE worked, so I'll look over the code. I'll post the SSCCE anyway.

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12, that's good it proves you understand the basic concept. Now you need to look at your actual code to see what is different from the structure of the SSCCE. So I suggest you start with working code and add back in additional logic one piece at a time until is stops working. That way you isolate where the problem occurs and you have more information to provide when you ask a question if you can't solve the problem. Then you provide a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem with the minimal amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add a listener to listen for resize-events from the `JFrame`.
When the `JFrame` is being resized, the method `componentResized`, will be called. Then you can get the current size of the `JFrame` and set is as the size for the `Canvas`.

```
JFrame component = new JFrame("My Frame");

component.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() 
{  
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {
        Component c = evt.getComponent();
        Dimension dim = c.getSize();

        // process the Dimension and set your Canvas size
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct, Compatible, Example):

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // The thread
    private Thread thread;

    // The Canvas
    private Display display;

    // Start the game and it's thread
    public synchronized void start() {
        // Create the thread
        thread = new Thread(this, "Game");
        // Start the thread
        thread.start();
    }

    // The run method
    public void run() {
        // SETUP THE JFRAME

        // Create the Display
        display = new Display(700, 500);
        // Set the title of the JFrame
        setTitle("Game");
        // Set the JFrame to not be resizable
        setResizable(false);
        // Add the Display to the frame
        add(display);
        // Pack the JFrame
        pack();
        // Set the location
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // Add a window listener
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            // When the window is being closed
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                // Stop the game
                stop();
            }
        });
        // Show the JFrame
        setVisible(true);

        try {
            // Make the thread wait for two seconds, so that the change is visible
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Print the error message
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // CHANGE THE SIZE OF THE JFRAME
        // Pretend that this is used for changing the size of the game window
        // by the user, later in the game. I'm just testing it now, when I don't
        // have extremely much code

        // Change the size of the Display
        display.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        // Pack the JFrame
        pack();
    }

    // Stop the game and it's thread
    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            // Join the thread
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Print the error message
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Exit the program
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // The main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create and start a new Game
        new Game().start();
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Close, but not quite a SSCCE. We don't have access to your Display class so we can't execute your code. For a proper SSCCE you would just use a basic JPanel. First, with a JPanel the SSCCE is smaller because you don't need to post the code. Secondly you first want to make sure the problem is NOT with your custom code. So if it woks with a JPanel, but not your custom Display class then you know the problem is something with the Display class. Another clue to solving the problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot that class. I'll add it later

Comment: `I'll add it later` - you missed the point of my comment. You should NOT be adding that class. Your SSCCE should instead be using a JPanel. The point of the SSCCE is to demonstrate how to dynamically change the preferred size of a component. So you use standard classes to demonstrate the concept to keep the SSCCE simple!